# How to create a JpaRepository but NOT using dependency injection

Tags: spring-data-jpa

In my application I am currently creating a JpaRepository via the usual mechanism, i.e. by defining an interface like so:

`public interface HistoryInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<HistoryInfo, Long>`

This works all fine BUT if the DB is not available or not accessible when starting up the application then the creation of the repo bean fails, the injection into the respective service (which receives that repo as an autowired  constructor argument) fails and as a consequence my applications main class:
`SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);`
fails as well. I.e. the entire application just fails with a gigantic stacktrace.

I would want to make situation a bit more user friendly in that the application at least comes up so far that it is able to display some (hopefully) helpful error message with an explanation and some hints what should be checked for.

That would require to NOT autowire the JpaRepository but create it programmatically, e.g. in said service's constructor but wrapped within some try - catch construct.

I don't want to give up that convenience that the JpaRepository mechanism provides but how can one create such a JpaRepository programmatically when there is only an interface defined and everything else is done automagically by Spring?

Is there some API-call to create such a JpaRepository for a given interface?
I would like to see something like this:

```
public HistoryInfoService( /* HistoryInfoRepository historyRepo */) {
    ...
    try {
        historyRepo = createJpaRepositoryFromInterface(HistoryInfoRepository.class);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // inform user about missing or non-reachable DB server and suggest remedies...
    }
    ...
}
```

Here I commented away the constructor argument which is normally provided via auto-wiring, but instead I want to create the JpaRepository using some method-call. That would allow me to properly react to the failed Repo-creation as indicated by the comment in the catch clause.

I searched for something like that but I must have been using the wrong search terms and found nothing so far. Any hints?

Comment: Can you put the stacktrace?

Comment: You could try lazy initialization `@EnableJpaRepositories( bootstrapMode =  BootstrapMode.LAZY )`. this will delay initialization of the repository until it is used.

Comment: @wia: the stack trace isn't important here. It's signals that the connection to the DB failed because the JDBC-connection was refused (when the DB server hasn't been started beforehand).

Comment: @Hopey One: the lazy initialization would not buy me much. I need to control the time of the repo's creation, i.e. it has to be executed at a given point (e.g. in the constructor of the service) where I can wrap it within a try-catch clause. I'll amend my question to make that clearer.

Comment: @mmo, nothing preventing you from using it in the constructor of a service.

Comment: @Hopey One: I was obviously still not able to get my point across: If I use it the constructor injection, then Springs JPA-Magic will try to create the repository bean before calling the constructor. If this fails it aborts my application. To allow my application to come up I need to be able to run the application even if the creation of the Repository Bean fails. That's why I would like to trigger the repo-bean's construction only once I am "safely" within a try-catch clause.

Comment: @mmo, from the doc _BootstrapMode.LAZY means lazy by default including injection of lazy-initialization proxies into client beans so that those can be instantiated but will only trigger the initialization upon first repository usage (i.e a method invocation on it)._. I haven't tried this, but from that I assume the crux of that is it won't initialize and therefore won't fail until you use it.